# How can a class extend both Thread and Gui?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I want to create a GUI with two buttons, such that when the first button is clicked, its colour will change back and forth between blue and white, and when the second button is clicked, its colour will change back and forth between yellow and green. I want the colour change of the two buttons to be able to happen at the same time, so I created two classes Button1 and Button2, both extending the Thread class. However, I now encounter a problem: in the classes Button1/Button2, you can't access button1/button2 in the main class (class Gui). I want Button1/Button2 to extend both Thread and Gui, but this is not possible; Java does not support multiple inheritance. Neither "public class Button1 extends Thread, Gui" nor "public class Button1 extends Thread extends Gui" works. How can I solve the problem?

Here is my code:

Gui.java:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Gui implements ActionListener{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private Button1 buttonone;
    private Button2 buttontwo;
    public Gui(){
        frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        buttonone = new Button1();
        buttontwo = new Button2();
        button1 = new JButton("button1");
        button2 = new JButton("button2");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container container = frame.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        container.add(button1);
        container.add(button2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gui gui = new Gui();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button1) {
            buttonone.start();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == button2) {
            buttontwo.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Button1.java:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Button1 extends Thread
{
    public void run(){
        while (true){
            button1.setBackground(Color.blue); //here's where the problem is
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            button1.setBackground(Color.white);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Button2.java is similar (omitted).

Comment: Your class should extend **neither**.

Comment: I don't think you understand the design of what `extends` does... perhaps you should read up on what [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) is in java

Comment: Tangentially relevant: why are you initializing in a constructor rather than in the main method, and why are you creating a new instance of Gui inside the Gui class?

Comment: @mstbaum: please explain your comment above. I'm not sure I see the issue.

Comment: Also, I don't think you understand parallelism. The button should not be a thread. The button should start an asynchronous task. On button click, submit an asynchronous task into a thread pool. The button click, as well as any other GUI event should happen on a single thread (the GUI thread).

Answer (score 7):

You ask:

> How can a class extend both Thread and Gui?

Your class should extend **neither**. Your question touches on several issues, including:

- Your desire to create a class that has both thread behavior and gui behavior is a strong indication that you're creating a "god" class, a class that is trying to do too much. Each class should have a **single** responsibility.
- Why would you ever want to extend Thread? Much better to create class that implements Runnable and then run it in a thread.

Also you state:

> However, I now encounter a problem: in the classes Button1/Button2, you can't access button1/button2 in the main class (class Gui). I want Button1/Button2 to extend both Thread and Gui, but this is not possible;

But this is a misuse of inheritance. You don't use inheritance to "access" another object's fields, and if you try to do it this way, your code will often compile but not work, since the gui object that is accessed is not the one displayed. Instead you want to use composition -- pass references of one object to another

Other issues with your code:

- Your threading code does not respect Swing threading rules as you're trying to make Swing calls from a background thread.
- Much better would be to skip the thread and `Thread.sleep(...)` and use a Swing Timer since this will give you the delays that you want and also will respect Swing threading well.

---

For example, the following code uses AbstractActions (think of these as super powered ActionListeners) in place of ActionListeners, and a Swing Timer to swap the text of JButtons, with different delay times. Note that I didn't want to post code that exactly solves your assignment but instead that shows you the concepts I'm talking about.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonFoo extends JPanel {

   public ButtonFoo() {
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
      add(new JButton(new SwapAction("Swap", "Fu", 1000)));
      add(new JButton(new SwapAction("Snafu", "Fubar", 200)));
      add(new JButton(new SwapAction("Goodbye", "Hello", 50)));
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ButtonFoo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ButtonFoo());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class SwapAction extends AbstractAction {
   private String text1;
   private String text2;
   private int delay;
   private Timer timer;

   public SwapAction(String text1, String text2, int delay) {
      super(text1);
      this.text1 = text1;
      this.text2 = text2;
      this.delay = delay;

      timer = new Timer(delay, new TimerListener());
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (timer.isRunning()) {
         timer.stop();
      } else {
         timer.start();
      }
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      private boolean firstText = true;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         firstText = !firstText; //toggle boolean
         String newName = firstText ? text1 : text2;
         putValue(NAME, newName);
      }
   }
}
```